# Dropping dataframes in a list based on column values

Tags: r

I have the following list:

```
df1 <- data.frame(a = rnorm(20), b = 010037)
df2 <- data.frame(a = rnorm(20), b = 010038)
df3 <- data.frame(a = rnorm(20), b = 010039)
df4 <- data.frame(a = rnorm(20), b = 010040)

ls <- list(df1, df2, df3, df4)
```

My objective is to drop selected data frames based on value in column `b`.

```
unwanted <- c(010037, 010038)
sapply(ls, "[", "b") %in% unwanted
```

So that, `df1` and `df2` would be dropped from `ls`, but I have no luck with it. Help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to `subset` the dataset and then `Filter`

```
out <- Filter(nrow, lapply(ls, subset, subset = !b %in% unwanted))
length(out)
#[1] 2
```

---

Or with `discard`

```
library(purrr)
map_lgl(ls, ~ all(.x$b %in% unwanted)) %>% 
     discard(ls, .)
```

---

Or with `bind_rows` and `group_split`

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(ls) %>% 
   filter(!b %in% unwanted) %>% 
   group_split(b)
```

Comment: Thank you @akrun. Wouldn't have made it work without your input!

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to solve your problem:

```
ls[sapply(ls, function(X) !any(X[["b"]] %in% unwanted))]
```